# Sqlalchemy eager loading of parent all properties in joined table inheritance

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following problem:

I have a hierachy of classes with joined table inheritance:

```
class AdGroupModel(Base, AdwordsRequestMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'ad_groups'

    db_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())

    # ----RELATIONS-----
    # campaign MANY-to-ONE
    campaign_db_id = Column(BigInteger,
                            ForeignKey('campaigns.db_id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                            nullable = True,
                            )
    # # ads ONE-to-MANY
    ads = relationship("AdModel",
                       backref="ad_group",
                       lazy="subquery",
                       passive_deletes=True,
                       single_parent=True,
                       cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    # # # keywords ONE-to-MANY
    criteria = relationship("AdGroupCriterionModel",
                            backref="ad_group",
                            lazy="subquery",
                            passive_deletes=True,
                            single_parent=True,
                            cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")


    # Joined Table Inheritance
    type = Column(Unicode(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ad_group',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }





class AdGroupCriterionModel(Base, AdGroupDependenceMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'ad_group_criterion'

    db_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)

    destination_url = Column(Unicode, nullable=True)
    status = Column(Enum("PAUSED", "ACTIVE", "DELETED",
                         name='criterion_status'), default="ACTIVE")



    # ----RELATIONS---
    # ad_group ONE-to-MANY
    ad_group_db_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('ad_groups.db_id',
                                                   ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=True)

    # Joined Table Inheritance
    criterion_sub_type = Column(Unicode(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': criterion_sub_type
    }



class AdGroupKeywordModel(AdGroupCriterionModel):
    __tablename__ = 'ad_group_keyword'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'Keyword'}
    db_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ad_group_criterion.db_id'), primary_key=True)

    text = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)


class AdGroupDependenceMixin(object):
    _aggad_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=True)
    _agname = Column(Unicode, nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def ad_group_GAD_id(self):
        if self.ad_group is None:
            res = self._aggad_id
        else:
            res = self.ad_group.GAD_id
        return res

    @ad_group_GAD_id.setter
    def ad_group_GAD_id(self, value):
        self._aggad_id = value
        if value is not None:
            self.ad_group = None

    @ad_group_GAD_id.expression
    def ad_group_GAD_id(cls):
        what = case([( cls._aggad_id != None,  cls._aggad_id)], else_=AdGroupModel.GAD_id)
        return what.label('adgroupgadid_expression')

    @hybrid_property
    def ad_group_name(self):
        if self.ad_group is None:
            return self._agname
        else:
            return self.ad_group.name

    @ad_group_name.setter
    def ad_group_name(self, value):
        self._agname = value
        if value is not None:
            self.campaign = None

    @ad_group_name.expression
    def ad_group_name(cls):
        what = case([( cls._agname != None,  cls._agname)], else_=AdGroupModel.name)
        return what.label('adgroupname_expression')




And I load the Keywords objects from the database with the following query:

    all_objects1 = self.database.session.query(AdGroupKeywordModel).join(AdGroupModel)\
        .options(subqueryload('ad_group'))\
        .filter(AdGroupModel.GAD_id!=None)\
        .limit(self.options.limit).all()
```

which returns obejcts of type `AdGroupKeywordModel`.

Unfortunately every time I try to access the properties of the `AdGroupKeywordModel` which are in the parent table (`AdGroupCriterionModel`) a query of this type is emitted:

```
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
    SELECT ad_group_criterion.destination_url AS ad_group_criterion_destination_url, ad_group_criterion.status AS ad_group_criterion_status, ad_group_criterion.ad_group_db_id AS ad_group_criterion_ad_group_db_id, ad_group_criterion.criterion_sub_type AS ad_group_criterion_criterion_sub_type, ad_group_keyword.text AS ad_group_keyword_text
    FROM ad_group_criterion JOIN ad_group_keyword ON ad_group_criterion.db_id = ad_group_keyword.db_id
```

which is strongly compromising the performace.

What I would like to have is that all the attributes for the class `AdGroupKeywordModel` which are related to the parent (and other classes defined in the relationship) to be loaded with the initial query and be cached for further use. So that when I access them I do not get any overhead from further sqlstatements.

It seems that eager loading is only defined for relationships but not for hierarchies. Is it possible to have this behaviour in sqlalchemy for hierarchies as well?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you should at least provide the code for all things you are talking about. Neither your relationships nor the thing referenced by subqueryload('ad_group') are visible in your code, so nobody can tell.

Comment: @knitti Sorry I did, not want to make the code too involved, I hope now it is clearer what I would like to do thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is: only `AdGroupModel` has a relationship with a `lazy=` definition (which is the keyword which defines eager loading for relationships), and the query only has a `subqueryload('ad_group')`.

The only point, in which `ad_group` or `AdGroupModel` touch with `AdGroupKeywordModel` is in `AdGroupModel.criteria`, which has as backref `AdGroupCriterionModel.ad_group`. I'm not familiar with the `subqueryload` syntax, but If I would want to eager-load `AdGroupCriterionModel.ad_group`, I'd define `criteria` like this:

```
criteria = relationship(
    "AdGroupCriterionModel", backref=backref("ad_group", lazy="subquery"),
    lazy="subquery", passive_deletes=True, single_parent=True,
    cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
```

The key would be in defining the right `lazy` also for the `backref`.

Comment: thanks this worked, seems that for sqlalchemy you need to specify the relationships as subquery from both sides

Comment: Thanks to you! I wasn't explicitly aware that this way asymmetrical definition of eager loading was possible. Now I have been able to optimize some of my models a bit.